# Featured slider with new jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to run slider with new jQuery because some functions like rotate are deprecated. Slider works fine when page is uploaded and I'm working to load image from clicked tab from right side. When I clicked on tab, current image and current active tab are removed and new image and new active tab are loaded correctly than I call my startSlider(); function again but i'm loosing variable value of i so my startSlider(); running without loading image and active tab background. Please help me to solve this problem. This is slide image:
[image]

and this is my jQuery code:

```
$(function() {

    var count = $(".ui-tabs-nav li").length;
    var slideSpeed = 5000;
    var fadingSpeed = 300;
    var i = 1;
    var $slider = $('#featured');

    var interval;

    function startSlider() {
        interval = setInterval(function() {

            $("#fragment-"+i).fadeOut(fadingSpeed, function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-tabs-activated");
                $('#nav-fragment-'+i).removeClass("ui-tabs-active");

                a = i+1;

                if (i == count) {
                    a = 1;
                    i = 0;
            }

            $('#nav-fragment-'+a).addClass("ui-tabs-active");
            $("#fragment-"+a).fadeIn(fadingSpeed, function() {
                $(this).addClass("ui-tabs-activated");
            });

            i++;

            });

        }, slideSpeed); // End setInterval function
    }

    function stopSlider() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    $('.ui-tabs-nav-item > a').click(function(evt){

        evt.preventDefault();
        stopSlider();
        i = $(this).attr('href'); // href's are values from 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5
        var id = $(".ui-tabs-active > a").attr('href');

        $(".ui-tabs-nav li").removeClass("ui-tabs-active"); // This remove current tab background
        $("#fragment-"+id).remove(); // This remove div with current image

        $("#fragment-"+i).fadeIn(fadingSpeed, function() {
            $(this).addClass("ui-tabs-activated"); // Load new image
            $('#nav-fragment-'+i).addClass("ui-tabs-active"); // Set active background
        });
        startSlider(); // Start slider again
    });
    startSlider();
}); // jQuery function
```

Comment: do you have a working demo? Or create one on jsfiddle

Comment: Here is jsfiddle. I didn't upload thumb images.
https://jsfiddle.net/mdLxoe33/

Comment: Here is updated with thumb images: https://jsfiddle.net/mdLxoe33/1/

Answer (score 0):

Well, startslider() is using variable `i` to fadeout and remove active class, and variable `a` for fadein and add active class.

After click you are using variable `i` for fadein and adding active class.
Variable `i` is global, so when your restart startslider() it will use that `i` to fadeout.

Also, after click you are removing an element, but in the code your show right now I do not see anything that adds a new element or loads an image.

Comment: I understand where is a problem but I don't know how to organize code and solve it. I want on click tab to load that image and after that to continue to loading next image but new starting slide loose value of i and I cant parse it as argument because than on loading page global variable have no effect. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/mdLxoe33/1/

Comment: don't remove(), to load a new image you can simply change src attribute: $("#fragment-" + id).children("img").attr("src", "http://example.com/img.jpg");

Comment: Thats mistake and I will fix it. I need that div for next time. I need to remove class "ui-tabs-activated" from div before click. I can use it fadeOut function, but that doesn't solve a problem with "var i".

Comment: My concept is wrong and I don't know what change to make to solve it. :)

Comment: I think after loading new image you need i=id (same image, prepare for fadeout in startslider function ), and a=i+1. Then do the if (i == count) logic again. You can replace that logic with modulus:

Comment: oops... modulus is: i % 5, it will make your numbers loop. Look up how that works.

Comment: btw, any problem if your values go from 0 to 4, instead of 1 to 5 ?

Comment: value is ok. count is = 5 and i start with 1 when i has a value 5 I back to 0 and after that increment it and set it to 1 before loading first image. And a = i+1 represent next image and next position for arrow on tabs. Slider rotate image fine, after image num 5, it load image num 1. Problem is with clicking tabs.

Comment: I make a little progres. I change remove and add fadeout effects in click function. And after that I set again global variable i (window.i = i) and startSlider(). New image on click is loaded and fadeOut fine but next image after, doesn't load (that is set with variable a = i+1). But after that slider Continue to load image fine. So, the first image after image that loaded on click, doesn't load and after that everything works fine. Check it: https://jsfiddle.net/mdLxoe33/7/

Comment: Try this, its not very efficient code, but seems ok now: https://jsfiddle.net/mdLxoe33/8/